# не могу понять почему ответ неправильный

Tags: python

в общем, результат вывода программы неправильный, не могу уже понять что не так и как исправить

вывод должен быть такой:

```
Рабочее время сотрудника Alex c 8 до 17 в 8, 17, 14 часов сотрудник занят
```

а получаю:

```
Рабочее время сотрудника Alex c 8 до 17 в 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16 часов сотрудник занят
```

полный код, может кто подскажет так же как код привести к более человеческому виду:

```
class Worker:
def __init__(self, name, worktime):
    self.name = name
    self.worktime = worktime

def test_input(self, busy=None):
    # if busy[0] < self.worktime[0] or busy[1] > self.worktime[1]:
    #     raise ValueError('Время занятости сотрудника не может быть больше времени его работы')
    return busy

def main(self, busy=None):
    if busy:
        # self.test_input(busy)
        all_time = []
        time_busy = []
        for i in range(self.worktime[0] - 1, self.worktime[1]):
            x = i + 1
            all_time.append(x)
        for i in range(len(busy)):
            # busy = busy[i]
            # i = i + 1
            time_busy.append(busy[i])
            s = set(time_busy) & set(all_time)
            all_time = [i for i in all_time if i not in s]
        return f'Рабочее время сотрудника {self.name} c {self.worktime[0]} до {self.worktime[1]}' \
               f' в {", ".join(map(str, all_time))} часов сотрудник занят'
    else:
        return f'Свободное время сотрудника {self.name} c {self.worktime[0]} до {self.worktime[1]}'


busy_time = [8, 17, 14]  # ввод времени когда сотрудник занят
Alex = Worker('Alex', [8, 17])  # ввод сотрудника и времени его работы
test = Worker.main(Alex, busy_time)  # busy_time - переменная не обязательна
print(test)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Worker:


    def __init__(self, name, worktime):
        self.name = name
        self.worktime = worktime
        self.busy_time = set()  # это фактическая занятость


    def main(self, busy=None):
        if busy:
            self.busy_time.update(busy)
            return f'Рабочее время сотрудника {self.name} c {self.worktime[0]} до {self.worktime[1]}' \
                   f' в {sorted(self.busy_time)} часов сотрудник занят'
        else:
            all_time = set(range(self.worktime[0], self.worktime[1] + 1))
            free_time = all_time - self.busy_time
            return f'Свободное время сотрудника {self.name}: {sorted(free_time)}'


busy_time = [8, 17, 14]  # ввод времени когда сотрудник занят
Alex = Worker('Alex', [8, 17])  # ввод сотрудника и времени его работы
test = Alex.main(busy_time)  # busy_time - переменная не обязательна
print(test)
print(Alex.main())
```

```
Рабочее время сотрудника Alex c 8 до 17 в [8, 14, 17] часов сотрудник занят
Свободное время сотрудника Alex: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался, не успел написать)

Answer (score 1):

```
all_time = [i for i in all_time if i not in s]
```

надо заменить на

```
all_time = [i for i in all_time if i in s]
```

Comment: Спасибо но все равно немного не верно, вывод получается `Рабочее время сотрудника Alex c 8 до 17 в 8 часов сотрудник занят` а должно быть  `Рабочее время сотрудника Alex c 8 до 17 в 8, 17, 14 часов сотрудник занят`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

спасибо

> Умка Баширова и Алексей Р

верный код:

```
class Worker:
def __init__(self, name, worktime):
    self.name = name
    self.worktime = worktime

def test_input(self, busy=None):
    # if busy[0] < self.worktime[0] or busy[1] > self.worktime[1]:
    #     raise ValueError('Время занятости сотрудника не может быть больше времени его работы')
    return busy

def main(self, busy=None):
    if busy:
        # self.test_input(busy)
        all_time = []
        time_busy = []
        for i in range(self.worktime[0] - 1, self.worktime[1]):
            x = i + 1
            all_time.append(x)
        for i in range(len(busy)):
            # busy = busy[i]
            # i = i + 1
            time_busy.append(busy[i])
            s = set(time_busy) & set(all_time)
            # all_time = [i for i in all_time if i not in s]
            all_time = [i for i in all_time if i in s]
        return f'Рабочее время сотрудника {self.name} c {self.worktime[0]} до {self.worktime[1]}' \
               f' в {", ".join(map(str, time_busy))} часов сотрудник занят'
    else:
        return f'Свободное время сотрудника {self.name} c {self.worktime[0]} до {self.worktime[1]}'


busy_time = [8, 17, 14]  # ввод времени когда сотрудник занят
Alex = Worker('Alex', [8, 17])  # ввод сотрудника и времени его работы
test = Worker.main(Alex, busy_time)  # busy_time - переменная не обязательна
print(test)
```